# Cannot change Menu Bar size

Tags: menu-bar

I've attempted to resize the Menu Bar using System Preferences to large - I have then restarted the laptop but the Menu Bar is still the same size. It shows large is selected in System Preferences. I recently did a reinstall of the OS, is this a sign that it is corrupted?

Comment: I have made an assumption about what you are doing and made an answer.  Tell me if that is wrong (I will delete the answer) and edit the question to describe exactly how you tried to increase menu bar size.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume you tried to make the menu bar larger with: `System Preferences` > `Accessibility` > `Display` > `Menu bar size Large` (drop down).

If so, I don't think you have understood what this does. This does not change the size of the bar (i.e. give it greater vertical size).

Rather it slightly increase the size of the font used in menus. This also causes the menus to take up more space horizontally.

There is a good example in this from [OSXDaily](https://osxdaily.com/2021/10/12/change-menu-bar-size-mac/). And it says:

"As you can see from the before and after screenshots, the difference between the two menu bar sizes is very subtle, it may be barely even noticeable to some users. But if you look carefully, you’ll see that the size of the actual menu bar remains the same whereas the menu bar items, font size, and icons have changed size."

I hope that clarifies what is happening.  And I do agree that the drop down could be better described, maybe as "Menu bar fonts: Default/Large".

Comment: thanks, this is correct, I was thinking it was for the menu bar size